# server error asp.net website

Tags: asp.net

created website in VS2008 with createuser and login page.
I was able to run the createuser page, but while trying to run the login page i received error:Server Error in '/' application.
resources not found.

thanks for help in adv

Answer (score 0):

Have you added login page to your website?